# Don't allow use of non existent keys on a given flow type

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

given this simple object: `{ id: 'x', value: 1 }`, in TypeScript if you try to do:

```
type foo = {
    id: string,
    v: number,
};

const bar: foo = { id: 'something', v: 1111 };

// refrencing non existent key
if (bar.xyz) {
    console.log('xyz'); 
}
```

you would get an error saying `xyz does not exist on foo`. How do you get the same result on **Flowjs**?

I've tried the following but flowjs isn't throwing any errors:

```
type foo = {|
    id: string,
    v: number,
|};

const bar: foo = { id: 'something', v: 1111 };


if (bar.xyz) { // no errors
    console.log('xyz');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow always allows for property checks in `if`s. You can use this as a workaround:

```
if (!!bar.xyz == true) {
```

Comment: Or `if (!!bar.xyz)`

Comment: @James that does not correctly issue an error as requested

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh yeah sort of realised after reading the question closer that you're trying to force an error - auto-pilot when you see code like `== true`. I've never used Flowjs before but I presume its the type coercion that invokes the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is still exist as an open issue. https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/106

As long as that issue is open, you can forcefully do type conversion `bar.xyz` to Boolean.

`if (Boolean(bar.xyz))`

You will get this error.

> 10: if (Boolean(bar.xyz)) {
>                        ^ property `xyz`. Property not found in
>
> 10: if (Boolean(bar.xyz)) {
>                   ^ object type

Comment: that's really surprising! I was adamant (secretly hoping) i'm using flowjs wrong and that there is way to make this work without having to do type conversion